# What's the difference between delete and reinstall of an app and just an upgrade on iOS and Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that is running on iOS and Android. I have been making upgrades and have these published to the iOS and Android stores.

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between if a user delete's and reinstalls vs just doing the update?

Comment: The difference between them is the **cache data** .One will lost cache data,another one will not.If cache data be useful in app, suggest that update is best recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

If you **Update** the app means all data in app like SQLite, Preferences, Permissions Cache etc.. would be available. 
And the keys generated for various operations like Firebase notification will remain same.

WHILE

If you **Delete** or uninstall app then all data like SQLite, Preferences, History would delete permanently and when you install app again, first time it will ask Permissions, Generate various tokens like FCM etc.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by tokens? What's an FCM?

Comment: If you have any third parti sdk integration Ex. Notifications or firebase analytics etc they are generating token first time when app installing. FCM means firebase cloud messaging.